# Arrange the elements of an array on the basis of no of matching terms

Tags: ios, objective-c

My database query results in an array of strings like:

(

XBARCD,

ZBAF,

DFBJ,

UJKD,

CFGKLO,

BCM,

AHUJD......
)

If search text is ABC, I have to arrange the above array such that the array is sorted in the following order:

1) all the strings that contain all the terms of search text

2) all the strings that contain any two terms of search text

3) all the strings that contain at least one term of search text

So, the result array should be of the following form:

(

X**BA**R**C**D,//On top since it contains ABC all three

//these 3 elements contain any two terms of search text
  **BC**M, 
  DF**B**J**A**, 
  Z**AB**F,

//these 2 elements contain any one of the terms of search text

**A**HUJD,
  **C**FGKLO

UJKD //contains none

)

The result could be achieved using basic for loops but the input array can contain hundreds of records. So, I need a way that is quick enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Searching for "AABC" gives the same result as searching for "ABC", if in the list we have "AABCD" and "ABCD"?

Comment: Why don't you try regex for your pattern ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri can u plz share some piece of code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using nested for loops would indeed take a long time. To flatten out the for loops (making an N-squared problem into a 2-N one), index the scores of each result prior to sorting. Try this:

```
NSArray *results = @[@"XBARCD",
                     @"ZBAF",
                     @"DFBJ",
                     @"UJKD",
                     @"CFGKLO",
                     @"BCM",
                     @"AHUJD"];

NSArray *searchTerms = @[@"A", @"B", @"C"];

NSMutableDictionary *scores = NSMutableDictionary.new;

for (NSString *result in results) {
    [scores setObject:[self scoreForResult:result withSearchTerms:searchTerms] forKey:result];
}

NSArray *sortedArray = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *result1, NSString *result2) {
    NSInteger score1 = [scores[result1] integerValue];
    NSInteger score2 = [scores[result2] integerValue];

    return score1 < score2;
}];

// To sort alphabetically
sortedArray = [sortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *result1, NSString *result2) {
    return [result1 compare:result2];
}];

NSLog(@"Sorted array: %@", sortedArray);
```

Where the scoring method is:

```
- (NSNumber *)scoreForResult:(NSString *)result withSearchTerms:(NSArray *)searchTerms {

    NSInteger score = 0;

    for (NSString *searchTerm in searchTerms) {

        if ([result containsString:searchTerm])
            score++;
    }

    return @(score);
}
```

Comment: `return [scores[result1] compare:scores[result2];` instead? But this doesn't sort alphabetically (this that the user want that?) when the score is the same.

Comment: Sorting an array alphabetically is trivial (and not specifically requested by the OP). I like the use of `compare` instead!

Comment: thanks & +1 for ur efforts. But can i get alphabetically sorted array for same score value.